# AngularJS with ASP.NET MVC5 - using routeProvider with templates but also adding angularJs bound data in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Good morning,

I am building an MVC5 application that includes a SPA (single page application) which runs in a small part of my bigger ASP.NET MVC5 application.

So here is my angular app setup:

```
var storeApp = angular.module('AngularStore', ['ngRoute']).
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/shop', {
          templateUrl: 'Templates/browse.html',
          controller: storeController
      }).

      otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
      });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

As you can see it loads **browse.html** which is an html template.

My **_Layout.cshtml** file has the angular app registered at the top:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="AngularStore">
```

Inside here, as with any ASP.NET MVC application it also has the following:

```
@RenderBody()
```

ASP.NET Mvc loads an **Index.cshtml** into the render body.

Here is my Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Shop";
    ViewBag.InitModule = "AngularStore";

    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section MyScripts
{
    <script src="~/js/product.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/js/store.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/js/shoppingCart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/js/controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}

<div ng-view></div>
```

As you can see the div that has the **ng-view** angular attribute on it is where my browse.html template will get loaded.

> **This all works as expected but here is my puzzle**.

My browse.html template is a list of products. You can click "add to cart" and angular adds the product to the cart.

The thing is I want the count of the things in the cart and the money value to appear on the _Layout.cshtml. So in essence the count and money will appear no matter what template angular loads.

So, I want to put some angular stuff inside the top part (header) of my _Layout.cshtml that will look at the cart and show the count and money value.

This is probably easy but i'm having trouble figuring out how to get it to work and also structure it the right way.

Maybe I need to use ng-contoller on a  on my _Layout.cshtml?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

If you live in Melbourne i'll buy you a beer!

thanks
Russ

Comment: Can you post the sample code where you ended up with ...

Comment: Dude. That was ages ago. I don't have it any more. Sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

I'm also building applications that are mainly MVC but have several pages that are using angularjs and are mini-SPA's.  You're going to need a controller used at your _Layout level.  You can do this simply by creating a div at that level and using ng-controller directive as mentioned in your question.  You do not need to do anything with routes at all, ng-controller defines the controller to use, and actually I don't use angularjs routing in my miniSPA's (though I can see where you might want to if your url changes within a single page).

What I think would be more appropriate however is to have a Partial view (which you can render from your _Layout if you want it always to be there), and within that partial view use ng-controller so you can have one controller for your cart and another controller for your shop.  You have a number of options to communicate between the controllers.  You could use the $scope.$root, or store your products in your Session data.

Comment: Ryan, this is awesome and it work great. So what I have is my _Layout which has a partial called _TopHeader which has a div that calls my controller on it. I have one final issue that I have just come across. Inside _TopHeader I also have an MVC action link that is meant to go to /account/login but because I have all of the above wrapped inside  ng-app="AngularStore" my mvc route mentioned is caught by my angular route provider and I cant get to my mvc route, i just keep ending up in my .otherwise part of my angularjs route provider setup. What you think about this? Thanks Russ

Comment: @Ryan Langton...Hi Ryan/Russ, 
Can you please provide a sample code or project as to what you are saying for the original question? 
I am new to Angular and MVC and I am working on similar situation but what you explained went way over my head. here is my question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961911/how-to-use-data-ng-view-in-layout-cshtml)

Answer (score 2):

Keep a root controller in the Layout which includes header HTML. Define count variable in root controller and bind it to any header HTML element to display the count value. Now you can access the scope of the root controller in your nested controller (in your case **storeController**). You can set the count variable (from root controller) value inside the **storeController** which will automatically display the value in header as it's binded to some header HTML element.

Comment: This is a great answer too, thanks for your input. Russ