# Angularjs and ASP.NET MVC 5: ng-view doesn't work with @RenderBody

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am new in Angular, and have some issue..Please help.
Ng-view doesn't render the template. My code:

HomeController

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new Model();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

_Layout

```
<div class="container body-content" ng-view>
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

ng-app is added to `<html>`

app-route.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    formsWorkflowApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                 templateUrl: "Home/Index",
                 controller: "HomeController"
             })
             .when("/Form/SearchResults", {
                 templateUrl: "Form/SearchResults",
                 controller: "SearchController"
             })
             .otherwise({
                 redirectTo: "/"
             });
    }]);
}());
```

What is wrong?

Comment: It seems you are missing a few basic things by looking at your code.
This article should help you get on the right track: [Getting Started with MVC and Angular](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/806029/getting-started-with-angularjs-and-asp-net-mvc-par)

Comment: change the **ng-view to ui-view** and used 'ui.router' insted of ngroute, More details available on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573403/angularjs-ui-router-with-asp-net-mvc-routeconfig-how-does-it-work