# ui-router, can't navigate to another route

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router

I am having issues with angularJs ui-routing in Mvc app. I have seen several questions regarding this issue. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573403/angularjs-ui-router-with-asp-net-mvc-routeconfig-how-does-it-work) in particular seems to be addressing my issue. However I am unable to navigate to different routes.

**In my Views/Home/Index.cshtml:**

```
 @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<base href="/">

<h1> Index Page</h1>

<a ui-sref="login">login</a>

<ui-view></ui-view>
```

**In my Angular/app.js:**

```
  var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);

myApp.controller("LoginController", LoginController);


 myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

     $stateProvider
         .state('login', {
             url: '/Login',
             templateUrl: '/home/Login',
             controller: LoginController,
             controllerAs: 'controller'
         })

            .state('Index', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/home/index'
            })
     // Handle request for non-existent route
     //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

     $locationProvider.html5Mode({
         enabled: true,
         requireBase: false
     });


 });
```

**In Login.cshtml:**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
} 
    <p> Login Page</p>  

<a ui-sref="Index">Index</a>
```

**Route.config**

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

**In my views/shared/_layout.cshtml:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```

**Possibly related question:**

how does  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) and     $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode(true) fit in the picture ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `href` to navigate yourself to the login state, which is wrong. You should use the [`ui-sref`](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref) directive instead

```
<a ui-sref="login">login</a>
```

You should also use the [`ui-view`](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view) directive to show the state your are targeting to.

The official docs contains [short, simple tutorials](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/helloworld) that will help you getting started.

Comment: what error ? also, are you defining routing in your server and client ?

Comment: I am having a different issue that is possibly related. I have asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48979707/asp-net-mvc5-with-ui-view-content-displayed-multiple-times) as seperate question